# OpenGlES doesn't draw anything

Tags: android, opengl-es

i'm trying to understand opengl in android and this is my render and a cube class.. the problem is that on device the cube is not showing. Can anyone tell to my why? can anyone correct my mistakes?? Thanks to all and sorry for my english

Render:

```
public class Prova implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

int wi,he;
public Prova(int wid,int hei){
    this.wi=wid;
    this.he=hei;
}
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glViewport(0,0,wi,he);
    gl.glClearColor(255,255,255,0);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    Cube cube= new Cube(gl);
    cube.draw(gl);

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

}
}
```

Cube:

```
public class Cube
{

private ByteBuffer byteBuffer;
private FloatBuffer floatBuffer;
private FloatBuffer colorBuffer;

float[] buffer={
        0.5f,0.5f,0f,
        -0.5f,0.5f,0f,
        0.5f,-0.5f,0f,
        -0.5f,-0.5f,0f,

        0.5f,0.5f,-1f,
        -0.5f,0.5f,-1f,
        0.5f,-0.5f,-1f,
        -0.5f,-0.5f,-1f

};

float[] color={
        1f,0f,0f,0f,
        1f,0f,0f,0f,
        1f,0f,0f,0f,
        1f,0f,0f,0f,

        1f,0f,0f,0f,
        1f,0f,0f,0f,
        1f,0f,0f,0f,
        1f,0f,0f,0f,
};


public Cube(GL10 gl10)
{



    byteBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*buffer.length);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    floatBuffer= byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    floatBuffer.put(buffer);
    floatBuffer.position(0);

    byteBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*color.length);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    colorBuffer= byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    colorBuffer.put(color);
    colorBuffer.position(0);

}

public void draw(GL10 gl10)
{
    gl10.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT,0,floatBuffer);
    gl10.glColorPointer(4,GL10.GL_FLOAT,0,colorBuffer);


    gl10.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl10.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);


    gl10.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,36, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,floatBuffer);

    gl10.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

}

Comment: Your `onDrawFrame` method is emtpy?

Comment: Yes but draw vertex not in on draw but on surface created

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a wrong buffer as last parameter to `glDrawElements`. The buffer you specify there should contain indexing information and not vertex positions. You should use `glDrawArrays` instead since you are not using indexed drawing.

Not related to the problem, but you should also disable `GL_COLOR_ARRAY` after the draw call.